# Why are parenthesis required for calling member functions on dereferenced pointers?

Tags: c++

Why are the parenthesis surrounding the pointer in this code snippet necessary?

```
cout << (*pStr).size() << endl;
```

After looking back in my book I finally found a small mention of it in a footnote that I had looked over.

It says, "--this ensures that the dot operator will be applied to the object to which the pointer points."

Why does this not work?

```
cout << *pName.size() << endl;
```

I'm only asking because my book doesn't give a very good explanation and because I just wasted a lot of time trying to figure out why this line of code was giving an error for me. (I forgot the parenthesis, of course)

Comment: [For reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using `->`?

Comment: When I was writing the small program I was testing I didn't remember any particular way of calling member functions on dereferenced pointers. Only after it gave me a problem at compile time did I have to look back in my book and refresh my memory. The book does mention that it makes code more readable to use the -> operator, but I was only asking this question because I don't see why the parenthesis would be necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.` has higher precedence than `*`.  So `*foo.bar` means `*(foo.bar)`.

So this code is invalid because the `.` operator can not be applied to a pointer

(I used an example without the function call operator `()` because that also has higher precedence than `*` so it was getting complicated).

Remember that you can and should write `pName->size()`.  The `->` was presumably created to avoid all these parentheses.

Comment: Oh, it was an issue with precedence? I always forget about that, especially when working with comparison operators. Thank you. Solved.